# Visual theme prototyping

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm having lots of difficulty prototyping my themes. Everything out there takes css values of some sort and then compiles it, is there a tool or something sencha has that can make me see what im making?

How does everyone make their theme when creating their sencha touch 2 apps? Is using sass the recommended way for this even though its so trial and error/look better? Does Sencha Architect let me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To try out SASS without really changing and compiling your project styles, you can use this online tool to visualize how it would look like :

http://developerextensions.com/index.php/sencha-touch-2-1-themes-builder-demo

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you make use of `SASS` since it's not only the correct way to style your own Sencha Touch theme but also provide you some powerful [global CSS variables and mixins](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Global_CSS) that you cannot easily achieve through normal css.

By using SASS, you need to install `SASS` and `Compass`. Follow this helpful tutorial on how to do it:

http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/styling-user-interface-sencha-touch-application